# Unable to bootstrap node on windows node using chef and knife

Tags: windows, chef-infra, windows-server-2008

I've exhausted my options in trying to bootstrap a windows node running in azure. I have the workstation connected to my self-hosted chef server without any issues. I run the bootstrap command and get the following:

```
Creating new client for vm1
Creating new node for vm1
Connecting to 104.***.***.***
ERROR: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout
```

I know the username and password are valid as well as the IP of the target node. What are my options here for debugging such a problem? I believe the necessary ports are open, unless I'm missing something special. I have telnet enabled. Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: Does SSH work outside of Chef/knife?

Comment: I'm running on a windows node. I don't have an ssh server running or configured, but in the past I haven't needed an ssh server running on Windows.

Comment: What command are you running for the bootstrap? We also support bootstrapping over WinRM but the command is totally different so it shouldn't even be trying SSH.

Comment: Ideally I want to use winrm. I'm done winrm quickconfig in the target node. I'm just doing the standard knife bootstrap command. I pass in the host address, user and pass. Any doubts on that?

Comment: Yeah, the normal `knife bootstrap` is for *nix (or at least for SSH :). You want the `knife bootstrap windows winrm` command, see https://docs.chef.io/plugin_knife_windows.html#bootstrap-windows-winrm

Comment: thanks @coderanger!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy down from the comments, to bootstrap over WinRM you need the `knife bootstrap windows winrm` command.

Comment: Thanks code ranger :) You helped over in the slack community and this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

you can also bootstrap windows machine with following command. Core Chef now supports bootstrapping Windows systems without a knife plugin

```
sudo knife bootstrap -o winrm <pubic_IPV4_Address/DNS_of_client_machine> -U Administrator -P '<pwd>' --node-name <node_name> --run-list 'recipe[<cookbook_name>]'
```

where,

pubic_IPV4_IP/DNS_of_client_machine   --> Public IP address/ DNS of the client machine.
node_name                             --> String representing node name.
cookbook_name                         --> Cookbook that we want to execute on client machine.
pwd                                   --> password to connect with windows client machine

Note: Make sure to execute above command from **~/chef-repo/.chef/** directory.

If you are unable to execute above command with **-o winrm** option then install below gem packages

```
chef gem install winrm
chef gem install knife-windows
```